# How might computers have developed in a Islamic theocracy?

Tags: science-based, technology, alternate-history, computers

In this scenario, the first programmers are Muslim scholars living in an Islamic theocracy. They are educated in Arabic and understand the classics of Muslim science and theology.

## **How would their computers differ from our own?**

Are keyboards really optimal for the loose and flourishing Arabic script? How would an iconoclastic culture develop GUIs? How would programming languages imitate Semitic grammar? What would be the first applications of the internet?

### **Points to Ponder:**

Here are a few differences between secular and religiously motivated science:

| **Secular Science** | **Religiously Movivated Science** |
| --- | --- |
| Since science is impartial and intrinsically valuable, it is concerned only with the pursuit of truth and uninterested in applicaiton. | Since science is a form of worship, the scientist must concern himself with the social consequences of his discoveries. |
| Although science is universal, its primary fruits are for those who can afford to pay, so secrecy is justified. | The fruits of science cannot be bartered away; secrecy is immoral. |
| Science is neither inherently good or bad. | Different types of science can be inherently good or bad depending on results. |
| The scientist is an individual concerned with a universal pursuit of truth and not tied down to his community. | The scientist pursues a social obligation and has rights ensured by and obligations to his community. |

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128774/discussion-on-question-by-collisteru-how-might-computers-have-developed-in-a-isl).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there would be much difference.

The prohibition of representation applies at most to living beings, and a computer interface has no such things (Clippy excluded).

At most the propensity of Muslim art toward abstract representation would have made much more easy to develop the concept of interface and icon (why do we need a bin icon to delete files?).

Answer (score 6):

> Are keyboards really optimal for the loose and flourishing Arabic script?

European languages (French, English, German) are not, as AlexP pointed out, natively block languages. There used to be (and as recently as my own youth) classes in 'cursive', which was learning how to write in the old-fashioned letter-flowing-into-letter way.

As AlexP pointed out, our block letters are an instance of the limits of technology shaping society, instead of the other way around. It doesn't matter that it isn't optimal for the user, a fixed library of letters is the only way a chiseled-letter Gutenberg-type press (and typewriters after it) works.

[image]

> How would an iconoclastic culture develop GUIs?

Even without images of birds or people, you can have some pretty complex geometric patterns and the concept of windows (see this floor for an example). I don't see anything special about iconography to the development of graphic user interfaces.

[image]

> How would programming languages imitate Semitic grammar?

The most primitive programming language (assembler) works on the same Verb-Subject-Object pattern as Semitic grammar. This is the root language that higher-order compiled languages or scripting languages ultimately resolves to.

Modern programming languages have tended to develop around objects, which collect both functionality and description within some kind of logical boundary. Most objects are nouns, but they could easily be verbs instead. So, instead of a class telling you everything you can do with a "Door", you might instead have a class of every way you can "Open" things.

[image]

> What would be the first applications of the internet?

Where do you define the internet in a millenia of peacetime? At the first message sent over a wire - then it would be the telegraph (1684), or the first sound with the telephone (1876), or the first time a machine spoke to a machine (1920s-ish).

> How would computer development turn out differently if it was not primarily motivated by corporate profit margins?

With all respect to Mr. Sardar, the computer was not developed with profit margins in mind.

Please allow me to introduce you to [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage), the inventor of the computer. He was a mathematician, a philosopher, and a theologian publishing a work in 1837 entitled "On the Power, Wisdom and Goodness of God, as manifested in the Creation".

His day job was as a professor of mathematics.

Babbage came up with the mathematical principles behind a calculating machine, which he called the Difference Engine and an Analytical Engine.

[image]

Now, let me introduce you to [Lady Ada Lovelace](https://www.euro2day.gr/ftcom_en/article-ft-en/1265548/history-of-innovation-ada-lovelace-and-charles.html) who, as a noblewoman, had no need at all for money. She was, by most accounts, a brilliant mathematician, and a friend of Charles Babbage. She was also multi-lingual, and helped translate texts that Babbage thought might be helpful in developing his ideas. These treatises that Lady Lovelace added her own ideas to are the first computer programs.

[image]

Babbage's youngest son [Henry Provost Babbage](https://www.computerhistory.org/babbage/henrybabbage/) built the first working model of his father's difference engine using parts in the garage. It was his lifetime's work (first version built in 1910, and he died in 1918 at the age of 94).

[image]

Now, let me introduce you to [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) who invented the idea of the computer as a general-purpose machine. He identified many absolute limits in what computers can do and can not do ([The Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

I feel like I have probably understated Alan Turing’s contribution. He was the only man of his generation who saw how much more computers could be than mere math tools. The two men who are credited for inventing the next generation computer, Howard Aiken and Konrad Zuse, were both looking at these devices as merely calculators. It is Turing who opened at least Zuse’s mind to the broader opportunity.

His reward for his brilliance as a government engineer and codebreaker during the war was to be chemically castrated and thrown out of his lab at age 52. Turing may have died from suicide, but some argue that he died as a result of breathing in cyanide fumes from a do-it-yourself electronics assembly kit, as he continued his work from home, even though he was forbidden by law to share any of his work.

[image]

Finally, let me introduce you to [Steve Wozniak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Wozniak), who invented the personal microcomputer. He did it with a club of computing geeks in garages. The first version of the personal computer was in a wooden box he had made himself.

[image]

All of these inventors of computing were motivated by a passion for understanding, respect for their elders, or curiosity. None were motivated by corporate profits (none even belonged to a corporation, except for Wozniak, who worked with Hewlett-Packard, and later with Apple).

Comment: I am pretty sure that in most European countries schoolchildren still learn to read and write cursive. (And with a fountain pen not less!) In fact, cursive writing is commonly used in advertisements and such, which it wouldn't be if people could not read it.

Answer (score 4):

### By 2021, things will not be very different

Programming itself would not be a whole lot different.  The user interface would change, but the nuts and bolts about how programming works is all about logic circuits and abstracting many little processes into bigger ones.  Programming languages have certain unavoidably qualities unto themselves which are pretty much going to happen as they did no matter who invents it.

Also, UTF has matured to the point that Easterners can use computers in their native languages by now, so it would make since that the inverse would happen in your world.

**The 60s thorough early 90s will be different in other ways though.**

Free software would be more prevalent.  Most of the early concepts of software you use would not have matured as quickly as the proprietary commercial software we saw shape our world, but it would be free. So, something similar to Linux may have beaten Apple and Windows to market by enough to mean that pay-to-use OSs would likely have never been able to gain a decent market share.  A lot of the common software we use would also be free: things like Word, Excel, etc.  By the time capitalisms gets its hands on programming, the market will have so much freeware that it will be really hard to make a program worth selling.

**But, by the late 90s our timelines will start to converge.**

Just because software is free does not make you free to share it.  Any software that is seen as contributing to faithlessness will be banned and censored in Muslim nations.  So, early attempts at platforms like Facebook, YouTube, Twitter, etc.  will likely be shut down faster then Capitalists killed Napster.  Muslim invented Search Engines will immediately fall under strict government/religious control to prevent the spread of heretical information and many searches will yield poorer quality results because there would be so much less focus on engagement algorithms.  While our world invented engagement algorithms as a marketing tool, they have vastly contributed to user satisfaction.

This means that the internet as we know it would not happen until what ever version of Western Civilization your setting has picks it up.  A less restricted internet created with little concern for social upheaval means that Western Civilization will quickly develop a larger, more complete body of knowledge that your Eastern Culture. All the best repositories of human knowledge will begin to shift towards Western Civilization, and cultures all around the world will have to adopt Western Standards of networking, to tie into these networks.  So, English (or some other Western Language) will probably still become the standard of the internet regardless of where programming is invented.

Furthermore, the late 90s saw a dramatic shift in the scale of programming projects.  Before this, computers were so small and weak that a single programmer could make just about anything worth making, but as computers got stronger, larger and more dedicated development teams were needed.  For this you need intellectual property rights and capitalism.  While open source can produce some really good stuff given enough time, property rights and capitalism allow you to make good software much faster by paying large development teams to spend their whole work lives on development rather than seeing it as some side-hobby done by a loose collaboration of people.  So, the capitalist West would still be the source of the 3-d graphics revolution, and with it all the genres of gaming and cinema that grew out of it.

The only way to stop Western Civilization from becoming the dominant force of the information age is for Eastern culture to become more like Western culture before it all starts ... at which point Muslim control of the info age would be a sort of moot point.

Answer (score 2):

There can be quite a bit of divergence... even in the real world, much wasn't settled until the 1980s or 1990s.

The things we can be sure of:

- They'll be digital. While analog computing is possible, it's just limited utility for specialized problems... the domain of researchers from time to time. And then only until computing power increases significantly.
- They'll be binary. Other modes are possible, but not for electronic computers.
- On that last one, they won't get going (not really) until electronics make them possible. Vacuum tubes and relays are necessary. They might have their own Babbage, but the deck's just stacked against such a guy to invent computing prior. But on this one I caution you that it's possible, just not plausible (after all, who in their right mind could contemplate a moonshot with 1960s tech?)
- Printers. At least until they invent the Muslim paperless office, they'll still have printers like we do, only the direction of the printhead will change. They'll complain about ink cartridge prices too, I think. And you lazy Romans will just have to wait for the next OS version, which promises to make foreign left-to-right alphabets work better. Probably also means they go through a teletype phase before CRT monitors become a thing.
- They'll be plagued by off-by-one programming errors.

The things that can truly differ:

- Data entry. You've pointed out that the keyboard won't work. It's not the worst thing in the world, Arabic isn't Chinese, and modern keyboards do have layouts for Arabic... but I don't even think this world sees a typewriter in the same configuration as ours. There are other possibilities, for instance the [typesetter's keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etaoin_shrdlu) looks quite different than the QWERTY
- CPU architecture. This one's a big one that's biting us in the butt and has been for decades... we went with Von Neumann instead of Harvard. The former shares memory/storage between code and data. The latter silos them apart. This has security implications. Other even more exotic architectures might be plausible.
- Word length. The 8-bit byte only won out relatively recently... many other word lengths proliferated in mainframes, minis, and workstation-class computers well through the 1970s. While this will undoubtedly settle somewhere on the lower end (lower cost), that could be anything from 7 bits on up to 12 or so.
- Computing substrate. Silicon's just shit and always has been. But it was cheap to work with. Until maybe the early 1980s though, things might have shifted to other semiconductors, and we might have higher performance if it had.

The stuff that will end up looking downright alien (though also eerily familiar):

- Operating systems. Humans are still humans and they'll have their command line interfaces and GUIs, but will they settle on the cursor being an arrow? Do menus belong along the top of the screen?
- Networking stacks. Take a look through history to see how weird things became before it turned into ethernet/TCP-IP/browers. The physical hardware will be weird, the protocols, the software that makes use of it.
- Programming. Most of us doing that today are locked into choices made by people who aren't even alive anymore. A very small cohort of the pioneers of computing basically made all these choices, and [network effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect) being what they are, none of us have really been able to escape those ever since. While our world preserves quite a few might-have-beens (Forth, Lisp, etc), this isn't the full potential of the spectrum. Not even close.
- Because of the former, software itself will be different. Vastly. Try being a 50 yr old programmer who understands everything developed in the 1980s and 1990s as if he were born into it, only to see how younger people are taking to "apps" on phones that pretty much demolish all the old stuff. Virtually nothing here will be similar to what we have at the user level of experience. It's difficult to say what the killer apps will be, of course, since this is dependent on how available they are to common people both from a totalitarian/non-totalitarian standpoint, and just when/how they become cheap enough for everyone to own. That has implications too... do they skip the floppy disk era entirely, and skip straight to download-it-over-the-internet?

This particular facet of modern life is ripe for redoing it completely in your world, and we have enough history of our own world fresh enough for you to get all the details right (if you want to). Go for it.

Comment: "7 bits on up to 12" <-Data is best indexed in powers of 2.  The 8-bit byte has nothing to do with the number of characters the English language needed, but was an engineering choice to improve data efficiency.  4-bit bytes proved too small, 16-bit bytes too big, and everything in between that was not 8-bits made data addresses unnecessarily long.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Too many weird offset addressing schemes out there for me to think that this was done because it was the sensible thing. If more was needed, and you can't quite justify bumping that up to 16 bits, then it'd get 9 bits. Maybe later on their industry settles on 8/16, but maybe also it's cheaper to just go with the way things are.

Comment: The 8-bit byte was invented in the 50s.  Offset schemes are a newer thing were made practical by longer, less efficient addresses like you see in 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: The word size of computers in the 1950s was anything but standard. While it might be technically true that the 8-bit word size was invented then, all other word sizes were invented then too, and there were many.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

- The Islamic world was past its golden age long before the mongol invasions.
- Even if it had a second golden age, that doesn't mean that they would be world conquerors or that theirs would be the only religion.
- While widespread, Christianity is not the only religion, despite mainly Christian countries being the first to industrialize and to build world-spanning empires. So while Islam might be more popular than in our timeline, I would highly doubt it would be Is the only religion.

**Now to answer the question:**

I'm gonna be quite honest things would be exactly the same. Cultural and religious differences do not change human biology, and computers were made to interface with human biology. Honestly, your best bet is to look at what is used in the Middle East today. Anything of any cultural significance would likely have been added to the machine in its transition to Muslim users.

Comment: If you're going to present a frame challenge, please label it appropriately.

Comment: Things likely wouldn't be exactly the same because of the butterfly effect. Furthermore, doesn't the extremely wide array of keyboard, operating system, and graphics designs on the market today imply that computer design is not inevitable? If something as simple as a way to bring food from plate to mouth can differ between cultures (i.e. chopsticks vs. cutlery), why not something as complex as a computer?

Comment: @Collisteru all cultures bring food to their mouths with hands or utensils hield in hand what is your point?

Answer (score 1):

**Are keyboards really optimal for the loose and flourishing Arabic script?**

Yes, I don't think that there are any other feasible input methods. People living in countries with the Arabic script as their official writing system use keyboards to input text:

[image: Arabic language Keyboard]

The Arabic script contains letters used to form words much like the Latin script does. If a better input method for Arabic script existed, it would have been adopted by now.

**How would an iconoclastic culture develop GUIs?**

Many fundamentalist Muslims who reject detailed drawings of people and animals openly and freely draw buildings and inanimate objects.

Here is a prayer rug with a depiction of the Dome of the Rock on it:

[image: An Islamic prayer rug with depiction of the Dome of the Rock on it.]

**How would programming languages imitate Semitic grammar?**

The English words used in HTML tags would simply be replaced by Arabic words. The <strong> tag would probably be something like <قوي> and the <audio> tag would be <صوتي>.

**How would programming languages imitate Semitic grammar?**

Most computer programming languages use verb-subject-object word order even though English grammar is subject-verb-object because it is more efficient. As a result, I would expect programming languages to be the same way.

**What would be the first applications of the internet?**

Considering that this is an Islamic theocracy, any information on the Internet would likely be filtered (much like it is in real life).

The first applications of the Internet would probably be the same. They would involve connecting universities and government institutions with each other.

**Final Notes:**

I find it rather unlikely that the Middle East would continue to be run by Islamic theocracies if the Western world didn't invade it. There would likely be a similar push for secularism there, much like how Renaissance and early modern Europeans tried to end the influence of the Catholic Church on society.

We might have a similar scenario to our own world where the Middle East and North Africa is covered in tolerant, developed, and secular states while European remains a mess of constantly warring Christian theocracies.

Answer (score 1):

**How long is a piece of string?**

It does't matter the scientists, it's society that's the answer. You can have liberal societies where religion is present but doesn't try and dominate society and then you have the religious extremists that rule society enforcing their extreme religious views on society.

A liberal society could have computers no different to ours and an extremist society might run only text based systems.

Yon need to define what society is like and then work backwards to get your answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to tell the OP. Do secular majority Christian countries today use religious scholars to perform their work? Of course not. But there are groups like Answers in Genesis that do that stuff while denying all scientific evidence in the contrary.

Comment: Just look at the photos of places like Afghanistan back in the 1960's and today. Still Islamic country but women back then were no different to Western society at the time. They wore mini skirts and went to the beach. Now they wear a black sack and rarely leave home.  That's how much religion can affect society.

Comment: Iran was actually a pretty good place to live prior to the 1953 coup d’etat. It was pro-Western and tolerant compared to today. But the British supported the Shah and its authoritarian and more religious government over the semi-democratic government at that time purely out of greed and racism.

Comment: Ireland in the 1970s was majority Catholic but definitely not a good place to live. The Catholic Church unofficially controlled the government and made very conservative and theocratic decisions. The Church ran Magdalene laundries and mother and baby homes that were little more than labor camps where many people died of preventable diseases. The IRA then terrorized Ireland under a pro-Communist agenda and led massacres of Irish Protestants who had to emigrate to the UK or other countries to escape.

Comment: @Galactic  The Scientific Method as we know is was invented by the works of Aristotle, Al-Haytham, Bacon, Descartes, & Newton who were all religious scholars.  Need more recent examples? How about Albert Einstein, Werner Heisenberg, Erwin Schrödinger, John Eccles, Louis Pasteur, Max Planck, or Michael Faraday?  Not only do secular majority countries still rely VERY heavily on the work of religious scholars, but there would be no such thing as science without them.

Comment: When you read about what actually motivated most scientists throughout history to pursue learning the way they did, the number 1 reason cited is to gain a better understanding of God. What made the religious scholars of the Enlightenment so effective was not a lack of faith in God, but a lack of control by a Theocracy.

Comment: Also, the secular scientific movement is just as corrupt as the religious one. 
Governments and corporations control research grants and publication rights making sure that "impartial" research agrees with the motives of the financial backers which leads to all sorts of researchers fudging their methodologies to produce desirable outcomes.   In law, we know that we can not trust any lawyer to be truly unbiased; so, we make sure that lawyers of opposing views are given an equal platform to debate these biases, knowing full well they can not both be right.

Comment: Science is the same, if you restrict the scientific community to only the secular, then you remove most of the scientists who want to challenge flaws in the status quo. Organizations like Answers in Genesis may have flawed methodologies, but they are also a vital part of the scientific community because they are so quick to challenge flawed logic and help the secular scientists weed out problems that they are blind to.

Comment: @Thorne The OP defines the culture of his society in the Points to Ponder section and the government as a theocracy.  So, the OP has already done this, he just needs help figuring out the "work backwards" part.

Comment: @Nosajimiki No science isn't the same because religion goes from sponsoring scientists to burning scientists as heretics.

Comment: @Thorne Secular governments like the Soviet Union and China have murdered countless scientists who tried to show results that oppose state approved science.  You are not describing a difference between secular and religious oversight, you are describing the difference between representative and totalitarian oversight. Totalitarian leaders kill those who oppose them having nothing to do with religion or science.  Religion has the reputation it does because most leaders throughout history have believed in God(s) so statistically speaking, most totalitarian leaders have been religious leaders.

Comment: They killed them for their political views, not because they discovered the world isn't flat.....

Comment: @Thorne How about for discovering genetics? The Soviet Union's official stance on  agricultural biology for example was that grafting plants to one another was the right way to introduce biologically advanced crops.  Any Soviet scientist who tried to claim they needed to do selective breeding instead was executed for challenging state established science.  In both cases, the murders only happened because totalitarian regimes need to look right more than they need to be right.  You are correct that it was about politics, but so was the inquisition, crusades, etc.

Comment: @Nosajimiki So? A religious society could just as easily kill same said scientists for "playing god". Religion is just another form of politics. Some in control uses the system to remain in control.

Comment: @Thorne "just as easily" and "another form of politics" <- Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.   Religious Totalitarianism, when put into a position of power over a society, functions no differently than Secular Totalitarianism because the problem in both cases is politics having nothing to do with believing if the world was made by the hand of God or an accretion disc.   Scientists don't get burned in highly religious, non-totalitarian societies (See 20th century USA for example).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t agree with suggestions above that the current form of computing is some kind of Platonic truth, independent of the (largely Christian) context that led up to it.  The real-world history of computing is a direct outgrowth of the Enlightenment, which in turn was deeply rooted in Christian philosophy.

“Islamic” computers would by definition still be Turing machines, but that doesn’t say anything about how they might be arrived at, or how they would be physically expressed, or their relation to society.

For instance, one of the most prominent features of material culture in the Arab world is the central role of calligraphy and (relatedly) two-dimensional geometric patterns. You could imagine that where Western computers started with teletype interfaces, Islamic computing might have started with plotters. Perhaps (if you buy Sardar’s questionable contention that Islamic science is purer in its motives), the early focus would then be on a free-form exploration of algorithmic art rather than number-crunching.  Maybe early networking would be framed in terms of geometric tesselations rather than hierarchical org charts, and flat mesh topologies would come first – instead of a network that connects you instantly to anywhere, you would have a network where you have to “walk” through an abstract landscape of peer nodes, so that the internet makes local space deeper and more complicated instead of collapsing distance.

It’s a bottomless well of speculation, but the point is – even if the low-level technical details couldn’t be all that different – the nature of computers as we experience them totally depends on what they are created *for.*

Comment: *"It’s a bottomless well of speculation"* then you should have voted to close as opinion based instead of giving an answer.

Comment: For Worldbuilding, the threshold for "opinion based" has to be pretty lax, since the whole point is to discuss counterfactuals.  If nothing else there's a fairly decidable question over _whether_ computing would be different.

Comment: But not this lax.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take this in two parts, one minor and one major.

I'm going to assume that the hypothesized theocracy has competitors, with which they will conflict. Certainly this is what happened in our timeline.

First, your characterization of the differences between religious and secular sciences is flawed. Specifically,

"The fruits of science cannot be bartered away; secrecy is immoral."

would simply be wrong under a more-developed science/theocracy. The need to withhold the fruits of such science from unbelievers would provide a powerful motive for intense control of the dissemination of science - once it had developed far enough to produce useful/powerful results. The behavior of the Islamic world during the Middle Ages is no guide to how such a theocracy would behave once science stops being an intellectual exercise and starts driving technological development.

"Power tends to corrupt. Absolute power corrupts absolutely."

On your main point.

There is no particular reason that I can think of that a theocracy would develop a different technology to produce the internet - but the resulting structure would be very different. Among other things, the internet is the child of DARPANET, a distributed communications network developed to circumvent the communications disruptions expected to occur in the event of nuclear war. Once technology develops to the point of nuclear war, the same considerations would probably produce something similar. At first. If it became popular, as has happened to the internet, things would change.

As the saying goes, "Information wants to be free." (and code wants to be wrong), but this is anathema to a theocracy. The most obvious issue would be porn. Any Islamic theocracy which developed an internet and saw what was happening would be scandalized - and they would do something about it. Massive on-line snooping and analysis of messages and pictures would be the norm, and considered morally both justified and imperative. Presumably there would be a brisk trade in samizdat porn, distributed via sneakernet, but that's not the issue here.

The same considerations would probably apply to religious dissent as well. Theocracies generally don't respond well to the widespread dissemination of heresy. At the least, I'd expect the development of massive, very sophisticated packet-sniffing machines as part of every ISP server farm.

Additionally, the regime would act to severely limit cryptologic research, in much the same way the NSA has rather delicately tried to limit some mathematical research which impacts US codes. This is not hypothetical. About 30 years ago I personally knew a guy who had his PhD thesis classified out from under him for exactly this reason. He was fortunate that his university was able to get a faculty member approved to review the thesis and recommend approval, which was accepted. So he was spared the dreaded review/defense hearing which normally occurs, but it wasn't a good time for him.